# Two TListBoxes using the same TPopup menu?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I have one TListBox with 'movie' items and another one with 'snapshots'. I want to use one popup menu for both Listboxes. However, in the onClick event for a popups menuitem, how do I resolve which list box was used?

I tried this:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::DeleteAll1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  TListBox* lb = dynamic_cast<TListBox*>(Sender);

  if(lb == mMoviesLB)
  {
 ...
```

where DeleteAll1 is a TMenuItem in the Popup menu. The lb is always NULL so there is something missing here..

Comment: In your case, `Sender` is not the list box, so the `dynamic_cast<TListBox*>(Sender)` returns `NULL`. It is probably the menu. Just add something like `ShowMessage(Sender->ClassName());` to the start of your function to see what it is.

Comment: Good tip, Sender->ClassName().. I found that the Sender is actually the TMenuItem component.. question is how to work oneself back to the ListBox component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`TPopupMenu::PopupComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu.PopupComponent) property tells you which UI control displayed the popup menu, eg:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::DeleteAll1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TListBox* lb = dynamic_cast<TListBox*>(PopupMenu1->PopupComponent);
    ...
}
```

If the `TPopupMenu` is displayed automatically (ie: right-clicking on a control when `TPopupMenu::AutoPopup` is true), the `PopupComponent` is populated automatically.  However, if you call `TPopupMenu::Popup()` yourself, the `PopupComponent` will be NULL unless you assign it beforehand, eg:

```
PopupMenu1->PopupComponent = ListBox1;
PopupMenu1->Popup(X, Y);
```